# what are the good ways to deploy and manage python script on production server?

Tags: python, memory-management, windows-10

I've written a lot of python scripts. Now I want to run it on another computer which running non-stop to crawling, analyzing data and update to an sql database.
Normally I open a command prompt and run the scripts:

```
python [script directory]
```

But with many scripts I have to open many cmd and every script call an python interpreter, so It end up with huge mess using a lot of memory.
What should I do to manage these scripts.

Comment: You can consider tools like docker where you can restrict the memory/cpu usage to each container.

Comment: p/s: The OS is window 10

Comment: In the future, don't "ps" - tag your question properly (this one is already fixed).

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what OS your server is, but assuming that it's a Linux server you should probably research a process management tool such as [Supervisord](http://supervisord.org/) or [Systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/). These are tools designed to run and monitor your program automatically, and even restart it if it crashes.

If you're using Ubuntu 16.04 then it comes with Systemd out of the box, however I personally find Supervisord easier to configure and use for simple tasks.

These programs won't necessarily help with your memory consumption issues however. Sure you can place caps on memory use for a process, but that's not really going to help you if it stops your program from working. You're probably best to re-evaluate your code and look for ways to reduce its memory footprint or use a server with more ram.

*EDIT:*

You've just added that the OS is Windows 10, which makes the above irrelevant. You can use the Windows Task Scheduler to automatically execute long running tasks.

Comment: "You can use the Windows Task Scheduler to automatically execute long running tasks" - can it restrict the memory usage ?

Answer (score -2):

you can use `pythonw *.py` , and it will run in background.